# Meaning of 2 Chronicles 33, 6: pagan ritual involving fire and human sacrifices?

Tags: 2-chronicles

2 Chronicles 33, 6 reports:

> And he [Manasseh] caused his children to pass through the fire in the valley of the son of Hinnom

What does it mean? Did Manasseh physically sent his children to some pagan ritual involving the burning human beings (as the context seems to suggest), maybe in honor to some gods worshipped in the valley of the son of Hinnom?

Answer (score 1):

The Pulpit commentary says this:

> Verse 6. - **Caused his children**. Parallel (2 Kings 21:6), "his
> son," in the singular number (see also 2 Kings 16:3 compared with our
> 2 Chronicles 28:3). There can be no doubt that this worst of cruel
> abominations, learned from Ammon and Moab, amounted to nothing less
> than the sacrifice of the child in the fire. It is, perhaps, something
> remarkable that we do not encounter anywhere any description of the
> exact manner of administration of this cruelty, and of its taking
> effect on the pitiable victim. The solemn commands of Leviticus 18:21
> and Deuteronomy 18:10 bespeak sufficiently distinctly the prevision
> and earnest precaution of the Divine Ruler of Israel, through Moses,
> on behalf of his people. The following references all bear on the
> subject, and will be studied with advantage in order given: 2 Kings
> 3:27; 2 Kings 17:17; Ezekiel 20:26; Micah 6:7; Amos 5:26; Jeremiah
> 7:32; Jeremiah 19:4; Ezekiel 16:20; Ezekiel 20:26.

Comment: Similar rituals have been claimed for Cartthage (which is, of course, a westward extension of Phoenician culture). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punic_religion

Comment: The Bible never details atrocities but this verse tells us all we need to know: "And they built the high places of Baal in the valley of the son of Hinnom, to cause their sons and their daughters to pass through the fire unto Molech, which I commanded them not, neither came it into my mind, that they should do this abomination, to cause Judah to sin." Jeremiah 32:35 +1

Comment: @Anne The quote from Jeremiah is relevant but I can't agree with "The Bible never details atrocities" -- It gives detailed descriptions of beheadings, mass slaughters of women and children, disembowelments, public displays of the slain and mutilations of enemy corpses, done by Israelites as well as their enemies.

Comment: @DanFefferman  Yes, certainly it states such atrocities happened and there are rare cases of spelling it out to expose the horror of what happened, but it does not glorify the events, or portray them in a manner as we see in modern literature. Consider how only the bare bones of Jesus' crucifixion are stated then compare with "The Passion of Christ" film. We are never encouraged to elaborate gory scenes but to dwell on the sin at back of it all. Far, far more could, and would be written by humans outside of verbatim reporting.